# Call JSF action method from custom component with parameters and table

Tags: jsf-2, composite-component

I'm trying to make a composite component containing a table with a commandButton on each row, calling an actionmethod taking the row object as a parameter. It would look like this without being a custom component:

```
<h:dataTable value=#{bean.objects} var="obj">
    <h:column>
        <h:commandButton id="button" action="#{bean.doSomething(obj)}" value="Do something with obj" ajax=false"/>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

What kind of composite:interface parameters would enable this to work? I've tried with `composite:actionSource`, `composite:attribute with target="button"` etc, making the action parameter a `f:propertyActionListener` etc, but nothing has worked so far. As an ugly solution, I send the controller as a parameter and call methods directly from it, but is there a more elegant way?